# Turn Switch statement into if/then and if/else statement

Tags: c, if-statement

I want to make this switch statement into if/else and if/then statement.
My Switch statement is :

```
char option;
printf("Choose your option : ");
scanf("%c",&option);

switch(option){
    case 'a':
    case 'A': a = 20 + 10 ;
        printf("Addition process result:%d",a);
        break;
    case 'b':
    case 'B': a = 20 - 10 ;
        printf("Subtraction process result:%d",a);
        break;
    case 'c':
    case 'C': a = 20 * 10 ;
        printf("Multiplication process result:%d",a);
        break;
    case 'd':
    case 'D': a = 20 + 10 ;
        printf("Division process result:%d",a);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid option");
    }
```

Comment: I won't answer, because I think your code works better with a `switch` statement.

Comment: Make an attempt.  If you can't get it working, show us what you've tried.

Comment: There is no if/then statement in C.

Comment: Why do you want to convert to "if/then" or "if/else" statement? What do you think, such a statement looks like? Please show us an example. BTW: There is no `then` in C

Comment: It would improve your code more if you used `toupper(option)` and only use one value per case, than turning everything inside out to use "if/else"

Comment: Please keep in mind that SO cannot replace beginner's very first lessons in C language. Reading the text book again and search for a tutorial is probably more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You just do:

```
if(option == 'a' || option == 'A') {
    // do whatever
}
else if (option == 'b' || option == 'B') {
    // do whatever
}
```

... the other else if's

then for the "invalid option", you have just an else {}. If the first if or any of the subsequent else if's evaluate true, then all the others will be skipped.

Comment: ok, I figure out if/else. But how to turn into if/then statement?

Comment: @singlepiece000 What exactly does that mean?  If you made a change to your code, compile it and run it to test it.

Comment: @dbush What it means is that those words "I want to make this switch statement into if/else and if/then statement" are the OP's uncomprehending paraphrase of a homework assignment.  Perhaps the assignment was misleading, or perhaps something got lost in translation.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char option;
    printf("Choose your option : ");
    scanf("%c",&option);

    if (option == 'a' || option == 'A') {
        int a = 20 + 10;
        printf("Addition process result:%d", a);
    } else if (option == 'b' || option == 'A') {
        int a = 20 - 10;
        printf("Subtraction process result:%d", a);
    } else if (option == 'c' || option == 'C') {
        int a = 20 * 10;
        printf("Multiplication process result:%d", a);
    } else if (option == 'd' || option == 'D') {
        int a = 20 + 10;
        printf("Division process result:%d", a);
    } else {
        printf("Invalid option");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how to convert in if/then statement ?

Comment: @singlepiece000 What is `if/then statement`?

Comment: @YunbinLiu He doesn't know.  He copied those words -- without understanding them, and perhaps inaccurately -- from his homework assignment, which you've just tried to do for him.